# How much is this ride (cost to go on this ride)

Tags: word-usage

Usually we buy an entry ticket and can go on any ride,**(Water parks,  amusement parks)**  but at some places we have to pay for each ride. **Each ride we decide to go on, we have to pay for it.  (And each ride has a different price)**.  What's a natural way to ask that:

> How much's this ride?

I am not buying the ride (though I guess it sounds like that), rather I am asking "How much do I need to pay to go on this ride?". What's a natural way to ask this?

Answer (score 2):

> How much is this ride?

This is a completely normal and correct expression. It doesn't sound like you are asking to purchase "the ride" but "a ride (on the ride)"  The noun ride can mean both the rollercoaster and a turn on the rollercoaster.  Context makes it clear which sense you mean.

"How much is it" or just "How much?" are equally clear, but most rides have the prices clearly displayed on boards at the entrance, so you don't need to ask. Instead saying "2 adults" is normally enough.